# How to enable key 'space' & delete key on iPhone keyboard when I disable key a-z

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am doing a customized keyboard, but I want to use some default key such as space and delete key. This is the code that I use to disable key a-z.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSMutableString * character;
NSCharacterSet *disableLetters = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] invertedSet];

NSRange location = [character rangeOfCharacterFromSet:disableLetters];
return (location.location == NSNotFound);}
```

This is the Screen Shot  :(I cannot delete ក after disable other keys)

[image: keyboard]

Comment: but it should not disable 'space' & delete key as at that time it will return yes

Comment: I want to use space and delete key !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with your code that I've fixed so this will now work:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *disabledLetters = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "] invertedSet];        
    NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:disabledLetters];
    return (location.location == NSNotFound);
}
```

This code has now been updated to only allow space, enter and delete to be used.

Comment: I don't want to use number, uppercase or lower characters . I only want space  ,delete & done key because I put other letters on those keys ! Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code above so it now does this. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: It is the same as before! I cannot use all keys ! I want to use delete  , space, and search key because I will replace other characters with new keys!

Comment: As you can see the image I add above ! (I just add one custom key)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that the field could be prepopulated with text. Try again now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //NSMutableString * character;
    NSCharacterSet *disableLetters = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_"] invertedSet];

    NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:disableLetters];
    if(location.location != NSNotFound);
    {
       return YES;
    }
    else
    {
       return NO;
    }
 }
```

Comment: beside writing like this " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", can I write in other way that include all upper & lower alphabets ?

Comment: yes its best way to avoid Upper case letters along with lower case

Comment: I still can type the lower case letters, but I don't want this! You can see my edition above ! I want to use my keys instead of default, that is why I need to disable all default letters and number.

Comment: I still can type all letters ! nothing disable !

Comment: except space , it is disable !

Comment: your code disables all keys as my problem before! the answer  Ander answers above is correct, you can see !